# How to modify solution macro in VS 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, macros

In my solution (Visual Studio 2005), there are more than 10 VC projects. My OS is Windows 64.

In the `.vcproj`, there are many solution/project macros, like `$(Solution)`, `$(ConfigurationName)` and `$(PlatformName)`.

As you know, `$(PlatformName)` equals to `x64`, but what I expect is that `$(PlatformName)` equals to `win64`. How to achieve this?

Some people tell me to do as follows:

> "Build" --> "Configuration Manager" --> "Active solution platform"

and then new/edit the option. After modifying, `win64` exists under `Active solution platform`, but still the `Platform` shown as follows appears `x64`.

It has puzzled me for some days. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

$(PlatformName) refers to the project selected build platform, not the solution platform.  Unlike the solution platform which you may name as you like, the project platforms have fixed names such as Win32, x64, Itanium etc.  You unfortunately cannot name these freestyle.

Comment: I like the use of the word "freestyle" here.